# Parse JSON to an Array property of an Object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Currently I have an AJAX request which will run the following SQL statement.

```
select top 1     
         DrugQuestionId
        ,DrugId
        ,DrugQuestion as DrugQuizquestion
        ,CorrectAnswer
        ,QuizQuestionTypeId
from DrugQuestions
```

and return me one `drugQuestion` object, with the properties listed in the SQL Server table.

pertinent JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GetDrugQuiz.asmx/GenerateDrugQuestion",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        var drugQuestion = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        //everything prints to the console correctly
                        console.log(drugQuestion.DrugQuestionId); //5 in this example
                        console.log(drugQuestion.DrugId);
                        console.log(drugQuestion.DrugQuizQuestion);
                        console.log(drugQuestion.CorrectAnswer);
                        console.log(drugQuestion.QuizQuestionTypeId);


                    },
                    error: function (xhr)
                    {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

This works fine and gives me the answer I was looking for.  In practice, I need a `drugQuiz` object which has a property which is an array of `drugQuestion` objects.  I used the following WebMethod to attempt that:

```
//this is questions, plural mean to populate an array with a length equal to the row count
//of the query
     public string GenerateDrugQuestions()
            {
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                DrugQuiz qz = new DrugQuiz();
                qz.PatientId = 123;
                qz.DateTaken = DateTime.Now;
                qz.DrugQuizId = 1;
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 3 * from DrugQuestions", con))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            DrugQuestion dq = new DrugQuestion();
                            dq.DrugQuestionId = (int)rdr["DrugQuestionId"];
                            dq.DrugId = (int)rdr["DrugId"];
                            dq.DrugQuizQuestion = rdr["DrugQuestion"].ToString();
                            dq.CorrectAnswer = rdr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
                            dq.QuizQuestionTypeId = (int)rdr["QuizQuestionTypeId"];
                            qz.DrugQuestions.Add(dq);
                        }
                        return jss.Serialize(qz);
                    }
                }
            }
```

So you can see that a JSON string is being returned from the WebMethod.  When I use the WebMethod without actually visiting the page and hit Invoke, I get the correct string.  What I can't figure out is how to populate an array of `drugQuestions`, which is a property of a `drugQuiz` object.  What do I need to change about the following code to allow that to happen?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var drugQuiz = {};
            drugQuiz.drugQuestions = new Array();
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GetDrugQuiz.asmx/GenerateDrugQuestions",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        drugQuiz.drugQuestions.push($.parseJSON(data.d));
                        console.log(drugQuiz.drugQuestions.length);
                        console.log(drugQuiz.drugQuestions);

                    },
                    error: function (xhr)
                    {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

I need to be able to do something like alert(drugQuiz.drugQuestions[0].DrugId);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the returned JSON and push each item into the JavaScript array, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {
        drugQuiz.drugQuestions.push(item);
    });
},
```

If you want to do this with `parseJSON()`, then try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data.d);
    for (var i in jsonData.drugQuestions) {
        var question = jsonData.drugQuestions[i];
    }
},
```

Note: I am not sure of the names of your JSON objects, I am guessing that `drugQuestions` is the name of the array of `drugQuestion` objects passed back, if it is not, then change the `jsonData.` value to match the structure of your JSON returned.

Comment: Can this be done without using `each` (just for curiosity's sake).  When I look at what comes to the console when I use `var string = $.parseJSON(data.d)` it looks like it has all of the data in there, but if I try to use an indexer to access a property, it's undefined.

Comment: Yes, but I find the `.each()` syntax to be much cleaner, but with that said the question has been updated to show the `.parseJSON()` syntax as well.